# How to change map origin of rtabmap?

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm using rtabmap and rtabmap_ros as localization mode to recognize robot's global pose.
To make my map simplify, I want to change map origin from pose which odometry started to desired pose. Is there any way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295931/how-to-change-map-origin-of-rtabmap?/) by [tilt](https://answers.ros.org/users/36189/tilt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could add a [static_transform_publisher](http://static_transform_publisher) to add a transform prior to `/map` in TF tree. For example, if you want to change map origin from 5 meters, you may publish `/world -> /map` with such transform.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1